# Multiindex or dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchy, multi-index

I am trying to analyze results from several thermal building simulations. Each simulation produces hourly data for several variables and for each room of the analyzed building. Simulations can be repeated for different scenarios and each one of these scenarios will produce a different hourly set of data for each room and each variable.

At the moment I create a separate dataframe for each scenario (Multiindex with variables and rooms). My goal is to be able to compare different scenarios along different dimensions: same room, rooms average, time average, etc..

From what I have understood so far there are two options:

1. create a dictionary of dataframes where the keys represents the scenarios
2. add an additional level (3rd) to the multiindex in the same dataframe representing the scenario

Which of the above will give me the best results in terms of performance and flexibility.

Typical questions could be:

- in which scenario the average room temperature is below a threshold for more hours
- in which scenario the maximum room temperature is below a threshold
- what's the average temperature in July for each room

As you can see I need to perform operations at different hierarchical levels: within a scenario and also comparison between different scenarios.

Is it better to keep everything in the same dataframe or distribute the data?

Answer (score 0):

In general in my experience is more difficult to compare different Data Frames, so I would suggest to use one. 
With some practical example I can try to give better advice.

However, personally I prefer to use an extra column instead of many Multiindex levels, but it's just my personal opinion.